# How to make bold numbers in Beamer using Madrid theme?

Tags: beamer, bold

I am writing a presentation and using the BEAMER mode in the MADRID theme.
This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, wasysym, amssymb, amsthm} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\numberset}{\mathbb} 
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%


\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}         
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,font=small} 
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{dsfont} 

\usepackage{relsize}
```

Whenever I enter a vector s in the \bm mode, it works making such vector bold with \bm{s}, but when I use it with a number it doesn't work, e.g. \bm{0} = 0, making the 0 plain and not bold.
Any suggestion on how to make it work please? Thank you a lot!

Comment: The following minimal example works as expected: `\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $0$ $\mathbf{0}$ $\bm{0}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}` What do you have different that avoids **bold** zeros?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you load the `caption` and `subcaption` packages, you shouldn't be loading the `subfig` and `subfigure` packages. Anyway, `subfigure` is badly deprecated. What's your justification for loading it?

Comment: Off-topic: in your preamble you some package load twice, also you load packages which are load by `beamer` as are `graphicx`, `xcolor`, etc. `caption`  doesn't work well in beamer (it has own mechanism for that).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `fontenc` package in your document, you could try without it or you could load the `lmodern` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{
 %amsmath, 
 wasysym, 
 %amssymb,
 %amsthm
} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 

\usepackage{
%pgf,
tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\numberset}{\mathbb} 
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usetheme{Madrid} 
%\usepackage{xcolor} 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{subfigure}  
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}         
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,font=small} 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\usepackage{bm} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{dsfont} 
%
\usepackage{relsize} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
 \bm{0} = 0
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]